# What does the notation $q^k || n$ mean?

Tags: prime-numbers, notation

I am currently reading the paper "PRIMES is in p" and have come across some notation that I don't quite understand in this following sentence

> Consider a prime $q$ that is a factor of $n$ and let $q^k || n$. Then...

What does the notation $q^k || n$ mean here?

The full paper can be found [here](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf) and the notation described above is used in the proof on page 2

Comment: Well I use this as a symbol of representing *concatenation*, for which $$a\mid\mid b = \left\{10^na + b : b\text{ has $n$ digits}\right\}.$$ but since we have $a = q^k$ and $b = n$ with $q$ being raised to an *exponent* $k$, then this notation would be different from how I know it to be defined, for all $k > 1$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically, that $q^k$ divides $n$ but no higher power of $q$ does.

Comment: Another way of writing it is $v_q(n)=k$

Comment: @GTonyJacobs why is $v$ included? How do we even *say* this? With the two lines $\mid\mid$ then pursuant to one of the answers above, this is read as *divides exactly* but how would we read the equation, $v_q(n) = k$?

Comment: The '$v$' stands for 'valuation'. For a prime $p$, the $p$-adic valuation of a number is a measure of how many powers of $p$ go into the number. What I wrote above says that the $q$-adic valuation of $n$ is $k$.

Example: odd integers have a $2$-adic valuation of $0$. Integers such as $2,6,10$, which are $2$ times an odd integer, have a $2$-adic valuation of $1$. A number such as $96$, which we can divide by $2$ five times before reaching an odd number, would have a $2$-adic valuation of $5$.

Comment: It's a nice concept for talking about how the integers interact with a specific prime, and it extends to all rational numbers: $\frac54$ has a $2$-adic valuation of $-2$.

Answer (score 4):

It means "**divides exactly**" in the sense that $q^{k+1}$ does not divide n.

Answer (score 2):

It means that $k$ is the higher power that divides $n$. In other words:
$$q^k\|n\iff q^k|n\wedge q^{k+1}\nmid n$$