# Term and notation for the maximal exponent that gives a power of a number that divides some other number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, terminology, divisibility

Consider two integer numbers $a$ and $b$, and let $n$ be the maximal natural number (or $0$) such that $a^n$ still divides $b$. Is there some standard term and/or notation for this $n$ (as a function of $a$ and $b$)?

Of course, this notion applies not only to integers: $a$ and $b$ could be elements of any commutative ring or semi-ring, or of a commutative (multiplicative) monoid.

Comment: We write $a^n\| b$ to indicate that $a^n$ exactly divides $b$; cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657112/what-does-the-notation-qk-n-mean); also we write $n=v_a(b)$

Comment: Cf. [p-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(algebra)#p-adic_valuation)